# HP Stacking Not Joining

Tags: hp, stacking

I have 2 HP 2920 switches and they aren't stacking as I'm expecting.
Both models are the J9729A, however one is Aruba branded and one is the original HP brand. Everywhere I read this shouldn't be an issue, and the Aruba rebrand was simply that - a rebrand with no technical change.

Both switches are detecting the stacking module in the rear - both have the module light lit. However there doesn't appear to be a link between the switches as the port 1 and/or port 2 lights are not lit. As well running `show stacking detail` shows both ports as inactive. I've tried connecting the stacking ports in all combinations 1>1 , 1>2 , 2>1 and 2>2.

Stacking is enabled on both, and I've tried following the procedures here with no luck. http://h22208.www2.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/WB/15-18/5998-8156_wb_2926_atmg/content/ch06s02.html

I've tried firmwares 16.03.0003, 16.03.0007, and 16.05.0007 (Latest).

I've now tried doing an `erase all` and `stacking factory-reset` on both, then powered on one switch fully, entered `stacking set-stack`, then the other. Still not detecting the link and both switches are acting as their own Commander.

Do you have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Sounds like the cable is bad - have you tried another one? I think they are standard SFF-8614/8644 cables like the ones used for SAS.

Comment: Had that thought as well, and I'm currently getting another one sent. I hope that's it - will update with my findings once received.

Comment: Can you share the information from `show stacking stack-ports`?

Comment: @Roger So executing that was showing both ports as Down. After replacing the cable it's working as expected, both ports showing up on both switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was due to either a faulty or incompatible cable**

The cable which I was having trouble with has Amphenol branding on it and part number;
HP P/N: *691970-001 REV G*

The cable which is working is HP branded and has the J9735A Part Number on it.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: @Ron Will do in 20hrs - when I'm allowed.